# After Android Studio 3.3 upgrade, so my APK's will build but not not run

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

After installing i get a `Disconnected emulator-5556` message, while im running a different emulator (on 5554).. Even when i don't have any emulators of devices running!

1. I tried deleting all my AVD's
2. Wiping AVD data
3. adb kill-server && adb start-server
4. AS restart
5. Created a new user profile on my Mac to see if that helped..
6. Re-installed SDK Platform tools

When i launch my app via `run`. The device selector shows this. Is this way since a long time and didnt interfere with my work in AS 3.2. But after upgrading to AS 3.3 i cant run apps anymore

But nothing works, anyone ran into this issue before?

[image]

Comment: Are you running beta or alpha version ?

Comment: make sure you have installed usb driver

Comment: Im on a mac, no usb driver needed. I can see my emulator devices when i create then, but this ghost emulator keeps popping up. Im running on the release version AS 3.3 just went stable :-)

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm on windows. It happens with any and all devices I have and everything worked fine with the previous version of AS (so, it is not a driver issue).

Comment: @Morothar My problem persists... its back after a reboot. Did you already find a fix?

Comment: @MarkMooibroek No. I had to install 3.2 and go back to that.I hope that there will be a fixed versio in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For if someone runs into this in a couple of years. I tried a couple of commands and the ghost emulator magically disappeared...

First command (to see if a process is doing something with adb)

```
ps aux | grep adb
```

Second command (to see if files are opened by a process)

```
lsof -nP -i4TCP: 5556 | grep LISTEN
```

Shouldn't have worked, but it stopped the blinking emulator for me..

Answer (score 0):

> No worries, just go to SDK manager and check if the Update is Available for the SDK Platforms, or SDK Tools. this usually happens when we use previous versions and sudden date to the new version of android studio and tools or platforms are not ready or updated with that version. Android has the version compatibility issues.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwT6J.png)

Comment: Im up to date with all of the software in the SDK manager :-(

Comment: Then uninstall the plateforms and reinstall them, thats the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Android Studio 3.3. In my case I had the Videostream app on my Mac and it was competing for port 5556. Uninstalling /Applications/Videostream and killing the process freed up port 5556 and everything started working for me again.